# how to find specific word from "<table><tr><td>Hello td </td><td>I am td for testing</td></tr></table>" using regex expression.

Tags: javascript, html

Language : Javascript

My regex expression : 
/(?<=>).*?(?=<)/gim

this regex expression find innerhtml from any html tag.

My regex expression will return ::
Hello td

I am td for testing

I need specific word like "td" from htmlText not htmltag.

Comment: `htmlText = "Hello td I am td for testing"` You have no HTML tags in your "HTML text"... lookaround for `<` and `>` doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

Regex Expression that I required is`/(?<!<[^>]*)td/`